# How to loop over three variables in python while their sum is always equal to 1?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to Python and I need to iterate over 3 main variables to check the best mean error in an artificial intelligence models.

The 3 models are: Gradient booster, Random Forest and XGBooster.

Each model is fitted to the data separately. And at the end I need to ensemble them but the iteration is exhausting as there is 27 iterations to make.

The equation is as follows:

y_predict = x*gradientBossterPredict + y*randomForest + z*XGBooster

Where

1. x, y and z are between 0 and 1 (with 0.1 as step for each of them)
2. x + y + z  should be always equal to 1

I tried the following:

```
rmse = []
for (gbrCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1)):
    for(xgbCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1)):
        for(regCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1)):
            y_p = (xgbCount*xgb.predict(testset)+ gbrCount*gbr.predict(testset)+regCount*regressor.predict(testset))
            testset['SalePrice']=np.expm1(y_p)
            y_train_p = xgb.predict(dataset)
            y_train_p = np.expm1(y_train_p)
            rmse.append(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, y_train_p)))
            rmse.append(xgbCount)
            rmse.append(gbrCount)
            rmse.append(regCount)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
>       for gbrCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work fine with below syntax for FOR loops:

```
import numpy as np
for gbrCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
    for xgbCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
        for regCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
            y_p = (xgbCount*xgb.predict(testset)+ gbrCount*gbr.predict(testset)+regCount*regressor.predict(testset))
            testset['SalePrice']=np.expm1(y_p)
            y_train_p = xgb.predict(dataset)
            y_train_p = np.expm1(y_train_p)
            rmse.append(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, y_train_p)))
            rmse.append(xgbCount)
            rmse.append(gbrCount)
            rmse.append(regCount)
```

for sum always = 1 in loop, look below:

```
import numpy as np
for gbrCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
    for xgbCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
        for regCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
            #check if sum is 1
            if int(gbrCount+xgbCount+regCount) == 1:

                y_p = (xgbCount*xgb.predict(testset)+ gbrCount*gbr.predict(testset)+regCount*regressor.predict(testset))
                testset['SalePrice']=np.expm1(y_p)
                y_train_p = xgb.predict(dataset)
                y_train_p = np.expm1(y_train_p)
                rmse.append(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, y_train_p)))
                rmse.append(xgbCount)
                rmse.append(gbrCount)
                rmse.append(regCount)
```

for each result in same row and not each value:

```
import numpy as np
for gbrCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
    for xgbCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
        for regCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
            #check if sum is 1
            if int(gbrCount+xgbCount+regCount) == 1:

                y_p = (xgbCount*xgb.predict(testset)+ gbrCount*gbr.predict(testset)+regCount*regressor.predict(testset))
                testset['SalePrice']=np.expm1(y_p)
                y_train_p = xgb.predict(dataset)
                y_train_p = np.expm1(y_train_p)

                rmse.append([np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, y_train_p)), xgbCount, gbrCount, regCount ])
```

Comment: hoping there is a list named "rmse", it will work. Just know that after every iteration, suppose current values are 0.2 0.4 0.4, it will append the square root value followed by 0.2 0.4 0.4. then similarly for every iteration.

Comment: But I need each loop result to be at the same row, not each value as a row.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Also consider taking a small python course from any youtube channel / coursera. It's very simple, one week and you'll be able to focus on all your machine learning and not waste time on coding part.

Answer (score 1):

Please code like the following.

```
np.linspace(0,1,11)
```

or

```
np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)
```

or

```
numpy.arange(1, 1.0, 0.1)
```

Comment: But how to add a condition on all of them so the loop take all the iterations while x y and z are equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

This is just a Python syntax error. 
Omit the parentheses in this line:

`for gbrCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):`

and also in the other `for` lines.

That will solve your stated problem. But  also [note](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), in the `arange` docs, that you should instead be using `linspace` if you want to use noninteger step paramter.

As to making the sum equal `1`:

You already have   `if int(gbrCount+xgbCount+regCount) == 1:` Doesn't that work? If not, note that  floating point numbers are not exact, so that what looks like it should be `1.0` might actually be 0.9999, so that `int()` gives `0`. You should use  `linspace` or else use `np.arange(0, 10 , 1)` so that everything is integers (inside the loop, dividing each value by `10`).

Comment: But how to add a condition on all of them so the loop take all the iterations while x y and z are equal to 1

Comment: True. Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach I can think of: loop over two of the variables, and determine the necessary value of the third (if it isn't in range, just `continue`; or better yet, specify the range for the second variable in terms of the first, in a way that ensures the third can be in range).

Example, with integers in 0..10 summing to 10:

```
for i in range(11):
    # when i == 0, j may be 0..10, which we get from range(11).
    # when i == 10, j should only be 0, which we get from range(1).
    for j in range(11-i):
        k = 10 - i - j
        # proceed to do math with (i, j, k)
```

(For the floating-point case, this may require some adjustment due to the imprecision of floating-point arithmetic.)